# Bootstrap Multiple select dropdown list not showing as expected?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to have a dropdown list from which a user can select multiple options. After some research I found bootstrap multiple select component from [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#limit-the-number-of-selections) website.  The code below is what I copied from the website. However, it does't look like a dropdown list as shown in the screen shot below. I searched a lot but didn't find any good solution.

The code I have copied from [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#limit-the-number-of-selections) website:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Choose one of the following..." data-max-options="2">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Script part:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    })
   </script>
```

***Actual result:***

[image]

***Expected result:***

[image: Expected result]

Thank you

Comment: Are you including the js and css files? Your image looks like the standard multi-select. The links for the cdn are on the [bootstrap-select github](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select).

Comment: @Tyler Yes I have included those files, but still its not showing properly.

Comment: Bootstrap Select still requires a jQuery call to initialize such as `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`  Are you initializing it correctly?

Comment: @RobertC I have included this line of code, and have provided all the code that I have used, but still its not showing correctly.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you running and what other JS/CSS is being included? Your updated 'Actual Result' image looks like another script might be conflicting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The css file needs to be in the `link` tag not `script` tag. You need the following to achieve the desired output you want:

These are the required files. **NOTE:** the `link` tag for css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

The actual `select` DDL:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="2">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

The script section:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    })
</script>
```